# How to move windows 10 store applications to another computer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I need to move a free windows 10 store game (modern combat 5) to my friends computer. what can i do ?

I tried:

1- pausing download and moving existing game file in my pc(c:\program file\windows app\game folder) to new pc, and resuming it. but it didn't worked.

Comment: Why move? Can't your friend simply download it?

Comment: why would i bother if i could? we have an slow and limited connection in our university(kashan university of iran) 512kb 600MB weakly limit so no i cant. @duDE